# get asp:textbox value in client side using javascript function doesn't work

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This code doesn't display the value, I don't know why?

I have server control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Visible="false" TextMode="MultiLine"
                    Rows="3" Columns="23" CssClass="white-scroll" />
```

in javascript function:

```
var eventText = document.getElementById('<%=txtTest.ClientID%>').value;
alert (eventText);
```

I enter text then click on button that call the javascript function, but the alert box doesn't display the entered text.

EDIT: when I initialize the text with Text="some text", it is displayed in alert, I want to enter text in client side and get the value of it in the Javascript function.

Thanks

Comment: What do the alert display? or is there any javascript error?

Comment: The TextBox is **Visible="false"** it means it is hidden then where did you entered Text?

Comment: it set to true in another control, this is a part of other code

Answer (score 3):

Using label or textbox visible set false so it can access the value in JavaScript

Sol

```
1)
```

Make a div and set `style="display:none;"` so label is not display at UI(browser) but value can access in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you server Control is called "txtTest" not "txtEventDescription"

change your javascript function to :

```
var eventText = document.getElementById('<%=txtTest.ClientID%>').value; 
alert (eventText);
```

EDIT: ok, I see you've now changed the post to show the code and renamed the js control, so above is no longer relevant (for those who are confused by my answer) :-)

The problem is the `Visible="false"` - this control will not render into the client and will therefore not be accessible via javascript (as the HTML element does not exist client side)

So, hide the element using CSS and then call alert on it. Sample snippet

CSS

```
.hide-element {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML Markup

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" 
        Columns="23" 
        CssClass="white-scroll hide-element"
        Rows="3"
        TextMode="MultiLine"/>
```

JavaScript

```
var eventText = document.getElementById('<%=txtTest.ClientID%>').value;
alert (eventText);
```

This way you will definitely get an alert.
You alert is empty because you have not set the property `Text` for your `asp:Textbox`

Comment: how can you say it is "txtText ?

Comment: mm sorry I changed the nae here in the post and forgot to change the other, but that is not the problem

Comment: I clicked the edit link and saw the control name was different to the js script...he's now edited his code (I don;t have edit priviledges yet, otherwise would have edited his code to display the <asp:Textbox... that is now showing

Comment: +1 dave. @sourabh, that -1 was not fair. You can clearly see that OP has edited the question.

Comment: @Dave Long, i haven't given -1 bro :-)

Comment: np - thanks guys - i get that it might have looked like a rather odd suggestion at the time :-)

Comment: @Dave Long: updated with some sample code. hope you dont mind.

Comment: Thanks naveen - no problem - in fact, appreciate it :-)

Comment: I want to read the text that is entered by user not to set on the server side, I think this is may be the problem, can I read the value that is entered in client side?

Comment: ya u can read but u have to make that textbox visible than only u can get the value in javascript client side.

Comment: when I initialize the text with Text="some text", it is displayed in alert, I want to enter text in client side and get the value of it.

Answer (score 0):

Make it `Visible="true"` to your textbox and than test.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"
                    Rows="3" Columns="23" CssClass="white-scroll" />
```

Comment: this is a part of other code and sure it is visible while testing :)

Comment: but it is set to false in your question ??

Answer (score 0):

if "txtTest" textbox has visible="false" in that case its not render on html code on client machine and if it hasn't on client's html code then how javascript calls this textbox. Because when javascript search this textbox by its id it doesn't find and it gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

you can assign any other custom attribute to the control i.e.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Visible="false" TextMode="MultiLine"
                        Rows="3" Columns="23" CssClass="white-scroll"
 clientID="myClientID" />
```

and then access control using jquery like

```
var txtVal = $('textbox[clientID=myClientID]').val();
```

hope it helps.

Comment: when I used JQuery, I get the same result; when set text in server I get it, but if I set it on client side, no

Comment: then there might be some other issue, this technique is tested :)

Comment: this code is inside user control (.ascx file), is there may be a relation?